# Google Analytics. Transparent pass request from server side

Tags: google-analytics

I need to track short links using google analytics. Short link page is never show up to the user, but redirect request to the binded web-site right away.

So I can add google analytics only to server side and need to pass all request data, such as IP, browser, resolution to it.

Answer (score 0):

This project is a PHP project for doing server-side google analytics tracking, you could use it: http://code.google.com/p/php-ga/

Or, you can compose requests to http://www.google-analytics.com/utm.gif with the appropriate parmaeters on your own.